# NullPointerException while getting excel Cell despite having non NULL Row in Apache POI Java

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to read and write Excel files.Following is the code snippet generating NullpointerException:

```
   int rowcount = 0;
   while (rowcount < Header.MAX_ROW_COUNT) {
       try {
            gpnameRow = gpNameSheet.getRow(rowcount);
            } catch (Exception e) {              
            rowcount++;
            continue;
          }

        int index = 0;
        Cell indexCell = gpnameRow.getCell(0);
        index = (int) indexCell.getNumericCellValue();
        System.out.println(index);
        rowcount++; 
       }
```

`Cell indexCell = gpnameRow.getCell(0);` this line producing the NullPointerException.

What can be the possible reason of this error?

Comment: 'The reason' is `gpnameRow` is `null`.

Comment: Are you sure `gpNameSheet` has data in it?

Comment: yes 'gpNameSheet' has data.

Comment: Check whether gpnameRow is null or not

Comment: post the stacktrace please

Comment: You don't appear to be checking if the Row is null or not. What happens when you do?

Answer (score 0):

Please post stacktrace, are you sure that `gpnameRow.getCell(0)` is throwing exception, I think it should be next line i.e. `indexCell.getNumericCellValue()`
You need to check if the cell is null or not before invoking any method of it.

```
if( indexCell != null ){
        index = (int) indexCell.getNumericCellValue();
        System.out.println(index);
        rowcount++; 
}
```

While going through the sheet there might be some cells that are blank and those may cause null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your excel once..
here 100% sure that you are not getting your rows. `row is null` here so you are getting the exception.If some other cause let us know.hope we can fix.